# iOS UIPageViewController ScrollView offset getting wrong value

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a `UIPageViewController` and conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate` via

```
for subView in self.pageVC.view.subviews {
    if let subView = subView as? UIScrollView {
        subView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

I have a indicator(lower blue line) which I want to slide w.r.t to pageviewcontroller as shown in image.

[image]

But when I'm printing the offset value getting strange result, when I stop scrolling.

The Offset value increases as I scroll and when I stop it is giving 414.0 all the time.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    debugPrint("offset : \(scrollView.contentOffset.x)")
    let x = (1/3) * (scrollView.contentOffset.x) - 1
    debugPrint("X val :\(x)")
}
```

Logs:

> "X val :274.777777777778"
>
> "offset : 827.666666666667"
>
> "X val :274.888888888889"
>
> "offset : 828.0"
>
> "X val :275.0"
>
> "offset : 414.0"
>
> "X val :137.0"

What's wrong I'm doing ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
 let point = scrollView.contentOffset
 let percentComplete = fabs(point.x - self.view.frame.size.width)/self.view.frame.size.width
 print("percentComplete: \(percentComplete)")
}
```

Comment: It will not work as the value is coming 414 after scrolling